# Detecting candlestick pattern

Tags: image-recognition

I have a question about a simple box drawing algorithm done in a chart.

A box should be drawn over 3 certain candlesticks.
The three candlesticks are classified like: the highs and lows of the left and right candlesticks are biggger/lower than the high and the low of the middle one. So the left and right candlestick cover the middle one.

If this pattern is detected, a rectangled (dashed) box should mark that pattern with top box of the highest high and the lowest low of the three candlesticks.

Has anybody an idea, how to box the candlestick pattern with a dashed box line?

I have solved the problem with plotshape so far:

Pattern = high[2] > high[1] and low[2] < low[1] and
high > high[1] and low < low[1]

plotshape(Pattern, style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, color=color.red)

But I would like to box the three candlesticks. Don't know how. Or highlight them in any way else but with circles, arrows or similar.

Does anybody have a clue how to mark the pattern with a dashed box for example?

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no question is being asked.

Comment: I just updated the question and hopefully made it more clear.

Comment: What you posted has nothing to do with design patterns. It sounds like you want to recognize and highlight specific shapes

Comment: You will be right I guess. Well, I am not used to the special wording and declaration of different topics in algorithms because I am just a beginner.

Comment: Please provide some code.